# Chrome extension in Angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension for google chrome browser using Angular 4. I just need the url and title of the page, where I am clicking on the browser icon(click event). So far I have done following things

I have created a eventPage and that page is getting called when I click the icon of extension. Code=>

```
if (typeof chrome.browserAction !== 'undefined') {
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        listService.getBookmarks().then(bookmarkLists => {
            bookmarkLists = bookmarkLists;
            getSelectedTab(bookmarkLists);
        });
    });
} else {
    console.log('EventPage initialized');
}

function getSelectedTab(bookmarkLists) {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        let newBookmark: Object = {
            name: tab.title,
            url: tab.url
        };
        bookmarkLists.push(newBookmark);
        listService.setBookmarks(bookmarkLists);
    });
}
```

`listService.getBookmarks` => listService has a method getBookmarks which already has some data as key, value pair.

IF anybody can tell just how to get the URL and Title of the page where I am triggering click on the extension click.

**Suggested Edits**
Manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Extension",
  "description": "This extension ...",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],

  "background": {
    "page": "index.html",
    "persistent": false
  },

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Comment: You already have the [`tabs.Tab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) object in your `onClicked` handler, which will contain the [`url` and `title` if you have the `tabs` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#property-Tab-url). I'd have to double check, but I also thought it was available with the `activeTab` permission.

Comment: @Makyen I have given 'activeTab' and 'tabs' permission but still I'm not getting url and title.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: More specifically, please provide your *manifest.json* and show where you are trying to use the `url` and `title` from the `tabs.Tab` object obtained from the `onClicked` event. BTW: [`tabs.getSelected()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getSelected) is deprecated and should not be used for new development. You should be using [`tabs.query()`]() instead. I'm not really sure why you are using `tabs.getSelected()` in this code anyway, when you already have the information you are getting from it where you call it in the `browserAction.onClicked` handler.

Comment: Thanks @Makyen I have removed `tabs.getSelected()` and now using `chrome.tabs.query`, this way I'm atleast able to get the url and title. You can convert yoour comment to answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got the url and title in extension

```
var that = this;
chrome.tabs.query({
    currentWindow: true,
    active: true
}, function(tabs) {
  console.log(tabs[0]);
  if (tabs.length > 0) {
    if (tabs[0].url !== undefined && tabs[0].url !== null && tabs[0].url !== '') {
      that.tabId = tabs[0].id;
      that.tabURL = tabs[0].url;
      that.tabTitle = tabs[0].title;
      that.favIconUrl = tabs[0].favIconUrl;
    }
  }
});
```

include this file on top of the component

```
///<reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/chrome/index.d.ts" />
```